# oracle explicit cursor loop

Tags: oracle, loops, cursor

I want to replace the domain name using cursor without a loop, which is an explicit cursor. but I also want to changes all the same domain names in the database by given pass a string.
example:  exec PR_Q3( 'usa.com','hotmail.com');  all the domain name with 'usa.com'in database will change to 'hotmail.com'.

```
create or replace procedure PR_Q3
(old_email in varchar2, new_email in varchar2)
authid current_user
is 
cursor E_info is select Email_Address from broker
where REGEXP_LIKE (substr(Email_Address, instr(Email_Address,'@')+1), old_email);
v_email E_info%rowtype;
begin 
open E_info;
loop
fetch E_info into v_email;
exit when E_info%notfound;
update broker set 
Email_Address = replace(Email_Address,substr(Email_Address,instr(Email_Address,'@')+1),new_email) 
where Email_Address = v_email.Email_Address;
end loop;
close E_info;
end PR_Q3;
```

it works if I delete the loop, but it only changes the domain name once.
I need changes all the same domain name. 
I want to do the same thing without a loop. Can I?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following simple `update` in your procedure:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_Q3 (
>     OLD_EMAIL   IN          VARCHAR2,
>     NEW_EMAIL   IN          VARCHAR2
> )
>     AUTHID CURRENT_USER
> IS
> BEGIN
>     UPDATE BROKER
>     SET
>         EMAIL_ADDRESS = REPLACE(EMAIL_ADDRESS, OLD_EMAIL, NEW_EMAIL)
>     WHERE
>         REGEXP_LIKE ( EMAIL_ADDRESS,
>                       '.*@' || OLD_EMAIL || '$' );
>
>     COMMIT;
> END PR_Q3;
> /
> ```

Cheers!!